# Split file by multiple line breaks

Tags: bash

Let's say you have the following input file

```
Some text. It may contain line
breaks.

Some other part of the text

Yet an other part of
the text
```

And you want to iterate each text part (seperated by two line breaks (`\n\n`)), so that
in the first iteration I would only get:

```
Some text. It may contain line
breaks.
```

In the second iteration I would get:

```
Some other part of the text
```

And in the last iteration I would get:

```
Yet an other part of
the text
```

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work because `IFS` only supports one character?

```
cat $inputfile | while IFS=$'\n\n' read part; do
  # do something with $part
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution of **anubhava** in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=1; echo -n "$COUNT: "
while read LINE
do
    [ "$LINE" ] && echo "$LINE" || { (( ++COUNT )); echo -n "$COUNT: " ;}
done
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this (without COUNT), because I had escape issues with the awk solution. My text parts contained a lot of characters like `'` or `"` and needed to be passed to an other script via the `system()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk with null `RS`:

```
awk '{print NR ":", $0}' RS= file
1: Some Text. It may contains line
breaks.
2: Some Other Part of the Text
3: Yet an other Part of
the Text
```

You can clearly see that your input file has 3 records now (each record is printed with record # in output).

Comment: How can I iterate over that with a `while` or a `for` loop, like shown in the question?

Comment: With `awk` you don't need to iterate in a loop since awk processes input record by record. You can anything with each record (denoted by `$0`) and file be iterated by awk

Comment: oops, didn't see your answer...posted a dup ... :(  +1 and remove mine.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks so much. It is the same idea as your answer, just happened to post it few minutes earlier.

Comment: I don't know awk too well. I need to execute other shell scripts for each record. Can that be done with awk?

Comment: @MarcDefiant: Yes you can do pretty much anything like that in awk. If you can post your code what you were trying to do in BASH I will transalte that into awk (hopefully it's not too big :P)

Comment: As far as I can see, `awk` is an language itself. I would prefer an option without using awk, because it's an level of indirection. If no other option appears, I'll do it this way and accept this answer. Thank you for your help. I'll translate the BASH into AWK myself using the manual.

Comment: awk does have its own syntax and functions but I will still not call it a separate language. Unix tools like `sed, awk, grep, find, sort` are very tightly integrated with BASH and more often than not we end up using one or more of them while writing a serious script.